# Webpack compiled successfully but project does not load in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, google-chrome, npm

I am trying to build a project made using Angular.Whenever I am building it
using `ng serve -o`. It compiles successfully showing no error but nothing loads in browser.
Error in Console of browser is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "button" element.
Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "button" element.
    at getMdCompatibilityInvalidPrefixError (webpack-internal:///../../../material/esm5/core.es5.js:240)
    at new MatPrefixRejector (webpack-internal:///../../../material/esm5/core.es5.js:261)
    at createClass (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:11127)
    at createDirectiveInstance (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:10955)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12391)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12837)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12746)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12418)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12837)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12746)
    at getMdCompatibilityInvalidPrefixError (webpack-internal:///../../../material/esm5/core.es5.js:240)
    at new MatPrefixRejector (webpack-internal:///../../../material/esm5/core.es5.js:261)
    at createClass (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:11127)
    at createDirectiveInstance (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:10955)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12391)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12837)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12746)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12418)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12837)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:12746)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:795)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4085)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
defaultErrorLogger @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224
```

After using `import { CompatibilityModule } from '@angular/material';` 
and
`import {NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode} from '@angular/material';`
in `app.module.ts`.The project loads but is not responsive,
Output of console is:

```
    Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224 ERROR Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" ("er)="[relocateEvent.emit(query), closeSuggestBox()]" [(ngModel)]="query"/>

                        <mat-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#searchSuggestBox="matAutocomplete">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionList.slic"): ng:///FeedModule/FeedHeaderComponent.html@15:24
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1918)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:13038)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27190)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26997)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1907)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26996)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26925)
defaultErrorLogger @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224
ErrorHandler.handleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1284
next @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4707
schedulerFn @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:3839
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:238
SafeSubscriber.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:3825
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4116
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392
Zone.run @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4048
onHandleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4116
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:396
Zone.runTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:195
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:499
ZoneTask.invoke @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:488
timer @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:2040
15webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" ("er)="[relocateEvent.emit(query), closeSuggestBox()]" [(ngModel)]="query"/>

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224 ERROR Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" ("er)="[relocateEvent.emit(query), closeSuggestBox()]" [(ngModel)]="query"/>
<mat-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#searchSuggestBox="matAutocomplete">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionList.slic"): ng:///FeedModule/FeedHeaderComponent.html@15:24
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1918)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:13038)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27190)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26997)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1907)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26996)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26925)
defaultErrorLogger @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224
ErrorHandler.handleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1284
next @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4707
schedulerFn @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:3839
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:238
SafeSubscriber.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:3825
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4116
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392
Zone.run @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4048
onHandleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4116
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:396
Zone.runTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:195
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:499
ZoneTask.invoke @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:488
timer @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:2040
15webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" ("er)="[relocateEvent.emit(query), closeSuggestBox()]" [(ngModel)]="query"/>

                        <mat-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#searchSuggestBox="matAutocomplete">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionList.slic"): ng:///FeedModule/FeedHeaderComponent.html@15:24
Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" ("er)="[relocateEvent.emit(query), closeSuggestBox()]" [(ngModel)]="query"/>

                        <mat-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#searchSuggestBox="matAutocomplete">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionList.slic"): ng:///FeedModule/FeedHeaderComponent.html@15:24
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1918)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:13038)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27190)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26997)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1907)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26996)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26925)
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1918)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:13038)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27190)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26997)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1907)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26996)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26925)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:795)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4085)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540)
defaultErrorLogger @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224
search.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
search.service.ts:55 200 - Ok
                        <mat-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#searchSuggestBox="matAutocomplete">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionList.slic"): ng:///FeedModule/FeedHeaderComponent.html@15:24
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1918)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:13038)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27190)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26997)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1907)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26996)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26925)
defaultErrorLogger @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224
ErrorHandler.handleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1284
next @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4707
schedulerFn @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:3839
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:238
SafeSubscriber.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:3825
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4116
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392
Zone.run @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4048
onHandleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4116
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:396
Zone.runTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:195
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:499
ZoneTask.invoke @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:488
timer @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:2040
15webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" ("er)="[relocateEvent.emit(query), closeSuggestBox()]" [(ngModel)]="query"/>

                        <mat-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#searchSuggestBox="matAutocomplete">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionList.slic"): ng:///FeedModule/FeedHeaderComponent.html@15:24
Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "matAutocomplete" ("er)="[relocateEvent.emit(query), closeSuggestBox()]" [(ngModel)]="query"/>

                        <mat-autocomplete [ERROR ->]#searchSuggestBox="matAutocomplete">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestionList.slic"): ng:///FeedModule/FeedHeaderComponent.html@15:24
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1918)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:13038)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27190)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26997)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1907)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26996)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26925)
    at syntaxError (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1918)
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:13038)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27190)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:27110)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26997)
    at Object.then (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:1907)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26996)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js:26925)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:795)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:4085)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540)
defaultErrorLogger @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js:1224
search.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
search.service.ts:55 200 - Ok
```

I am trying to run project of loklak search locally.Here is the link to the project [Loklak Repository on Github](https://github.com/loklak)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your having an issue with conflicts as you are using 'mat-' prefix.
or, maybe, some external packages have that as their prefix which is creating the conflicts.

add the following imports :- 
for 'md-' prefix :

`import { CompatibilityModule } from '@angular/material';`

for 'mat-' prefix:

```
import {NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode} from '@angular/material';
```

---

have a look at this chain , it will fix your problem man.

> https://github.com/Teradata/covalent/issues/923

cheers!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply,the project homepage loads now but it is not responsive.The console show some more errors.I am going to edit my questions to include those errors.

Comment: Sure let me know...I would be more than happy to help you bruh!!